# What is the total Naruto runtime up to this point?

Tags: naruto

Naruto seems to be one of few longest-running series, and considering the number of episodes so far, this adds up to quite considerable time.

What is the total runtime - the time I'd have to spend in front of the screen if I wanted to watch the whole series (including any 'paraphenalia' like OVA etc), from beginning up to current point?

Comment: Are you including opening and ending songs? "Next episode"? Things like that?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Either way is fine - I guess these occupy varied length so they could make the calculation harder, so including them is fine. (let's assume they are just right for "necessary breaks")

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of 10-March-2021, after using [myanimelist](http://www.myanimelist.net) as a source for duration's I came to the conclusion that it would take you:

| Duration | Time of non stop watching |
| --- | --- |
| In Minutes | 32414 |
| In Hours | 390.2 |
| In Days | 16.3 |

This would mean that you could completely watch all Naruto media in just under two and a half week.
However, taking into account that nobody is going to watch anything for two and a half week straight. It would take an average viewer quite a bit longer.

Given that an average viewer watches around 5-6 episodes per day, or roughly 2 hours a day. It would take them about 174.3 days to watch the series to completion, and an additional 20.9 days to watch all the other media. For a grand total of 195.1 days total to watch *everything*.

### Series

| Title | Episodes | Episode Duration in minutes | Total Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Naruto | 220 | 23 | ~5060 minutes or 84.3 hours or 3.5 days |
| Naruto Shippuuden | 500 | 23 | ~11500 minutes or 191.7 hours or 8 days |
| Boruto next generations (ongoing) | 189 | 23 | ~189 minutes or 72.5 hours or 3 days |

### Movies

| Title | Duration in minutes |
| --- | --- |
| Naruto: Movie 1 - Dai Katsugeki!! Yuki Hime Shinobu Houjou Dattebayo! | 90 |
| Naruto: Movie 2 - Daigekitotsu! Maboroshi no Chiteiiseki Dattebayo! | 97 |
| Naruto: Movie 3 - Dai Koufun! Mikazuki Jima no Animaru Panikku Dattebayo! | 94 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 1 | 94 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 2 - Kizuna | 92 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 3 - Hi no Ishi wo Tsugu Mono | 95 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 4 - The Lost Tower | 85 |
| Naruto Soyokazeden Movie: Naruto to Mashin to Mitsu no Onegai Dattebayo!! | 14 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 5 - Blood Prison | 102 |
| Naruto: Honoo no Chuunin Shiken! Naruto vs. Konohamaru!! | 14 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 6 - Road to Ninja | 109 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden Movie 7 - The Last | 112 |
| Boruto: Naruto the Movie | 105 |
| Boruto: Naruto the Movie - Naruto ga Hokage ni Natta Hi | 10 |

### Specials

| Title | Duration in minutes |
| --- | --- |
| Naruto: Dai Katsugeki!! ... Special: Konoha Annual Sports Festival | 11 |
| Naruto: Takigakure no Shitou - Ore ga Eiyuu Dattebayo! | 40 |
| Naruto: Find the Crimson Four-leaf Clover | 17 |
| Naruto: The Cross Roads | 28 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden - Konoha Gakuen Special | 8 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden - Jump Super Anime Tour 2013 Special | 11 |
| Naruto: Shippuuden - Sunny Side Battle | 11 |
| Boruto: Jump Festa 2016 Special | 11 |

### Ovas

| Title | Duration in minutes |
| --- | --- |
| Naruto: Finally a Clash!! Jounin vs. Genin! | 26 |
| Naruto x UT | 6 |

### Onas

| Title | Duration in minutes |
| --- | --- |
| Kamiusagi Rope x Boruto: Naruto Next Generations | 1 |

### Spin-off

| Title | Episodes | Episode Duration in minutes | Total Duration in minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rock Lee no Seishun Full-Power Ninden | 51 | 24 | ~1224 minutes or 20.4 hours or 0.85 days |

As a side note, I feel sad for the people that had to wait weekly from episode one onward. That's 909 weeks (excluding double releases and breaks) of waiting 6 days for the next episode (Which is almost 17.5 years!)

*Information will be updated when Boruto next generations ends, and somebody boops me about it in the comments*