# What is the total runtime of One Piece up to this point?

Tags: one-piece

After reading [this Question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/10075/what-is-the-total-naruto-runtime-up-to-this-point) and the ingenious answer from Dimitri mx (kudos) and a related comment, I came to wonder how One Piece would compare.

The anime was launched in October 1999 and is still ongoing.

Comment: Ill see if I have the time to answer this one tonight (if nobody else did take the time to do so off course) :)

Comment: Considering that comment, [One Piece is far from being the longest running show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_series_by_episode_count). Imagine binge watching Sazae-san, with its 29.9 days worth of watching...

Comment: @Dimitrimx just read your answer for `naruto` on similar question. and after reading that m excited to get stats for `one piece` as well. That was really a great job done :):)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before I start with the actual comparison, I would first like to note that in the current point in time, Naruto and One piece do not differ to much in run time. But taking into account that Naruto is running towards the end, and Oda Eiichiro said that he is about the half way mark, we can safely assume that in a near future this will change. With that said.

Just like in my mentioned answer, I have been using [Myanimelist](http://www.myanimelist.net/) as a source of times. And came to the conclusion that it would take you 
**18945 Minutes of non stop watching one piece** (excluding cross-overs)
which equals to **315.8 Hours** or **13.2 Days**

making the difference in time about **1620 Minutes**
which equals to **27 Hours** or slightly more then **1 day**

This difference in run time is caused by One piece having:

- 220 more episodes
- 4 (soon to be 5) more movies
- 7 more Ova's
- 1 More special

Where as Naruto only beats one piece in

- Having a second season
- Having a spin- off series.

### Actual Serie

One Piece 710 episodes (currently), roughly 24 minute's/Episode* 
~**17040 Minutes or 11.8 days**

### Movies

- One Piece  **50 Minutes**
- Nejimaki Jima no Daibouken **55 Minutes**
- Chinjuujima no Chopper Oukoku  **55 Minutes**
- Dead End no Bouken  **95 Minutes**
- Norowareta Seiken  **95 Minutes**
- Omatsuri Danshaku to Himitsu no Shima 6  **95 Minutes**
- Karakurijou no Mecha Kyohei  **94 Minutes**
- Jango no Dance Carnival  **6 Minutes**
- Yume no Soccer Ou!  **5 Minutes**
- Mezase! Kaizoku Yakyuu Ou  **5 Minutes**
- Strong World  **115 Minutes**
- Film: Z  **107 Minutes**
- One Piece (2016) **Unknown**
- **TOTAL:** *777 Minutes or 13.0 Hours*

### Movies (Summary's)

All tough most of the ones listed under this tab are officially known as *specials*, I still decided to list them in their own sub-category of movies as I found it to be more fitting.

- Episode of Alabaster - Sabaku no Ojou to Kaizoku Tachi  **90 Minutes**
- Episode of Chopper Plus - Fuyu ni Saku, Kiseki no Sakura **113 Minutes**
- Episode of Nami - Koukaishi no Namida to Nakama no Kizuna  **106 Minutes**
- Episode of Merry - Mou Hitori no Nakama no Monogatari  **106 Minutes**
- Episode of Sabo - 3 Kyoudai no Kizuna Kiseki no Saikai to Uketsugareru Ishi  **105 Minutes**
- **TOTAL:** *520 Minutes or 8.7 Hours*

### Ova

- Taose! Kaizoku Ganzack  **28 Minutes**
- Umi no Heso no Daibouken-hen  **49 Minutes**
- Oounabara ni Hirake! Dekkai Dekkai Chichi no Yume!  **46 Minutes**
- Romance Dawn Story  **33 Minutes**
- 3D: Mugiwara Chase  **30 Minutes**
- 3D: Gekisou! Trap Coaster  **12 Minutes**
- Romance Dawn  **30 Minutes**
- Episode of Alabaster - Prologue  **15 Minutes**
- Recap (10 year recap, from start up to Impeldown)  **29 Minutes**
- **TOTAL:** *272 Minutes or 4.5 Hours*

### Specials

- Mamore! Saigo no Dai Butai  **45 Minutes**
- Nenmatsu Tokubetsu Kikaku! Mugiwara no Luffy Oyabun Torimonochou **42 Minutes**
- Straw Hat Theater *(5 eps. 3 Min/ep)*  **15 Minutes**
- Episode of Luffy - Hand Island no Bouken  **102 Minutes**
- Glorious Island *(2 eps. 5 Min/ep)*  **10 Minutes**
- 3D2Y: Ace no shi wo Koete! Luffy Nakama Tono Chikai  **107 Minutes**
- Cry Heart *(3 eps. 5 Min/ep)* **15 Minutes**
- **TOTAL:** *336 Minutes or 5.6 Hours*

Small side note: All tough I taught it was said for Naruto fans to wait a whole week, One piece fans had a even harder time having to wait 832 weeks or 16 years! With the sole exception being Hinati Fujinamai [Ending revealed to severely sick boy](http://www.kdramastars.com/articles/33654/20140818/one-piece-ending-spoilers.htm)

> JapNation AniManga reports that Eiichiro Oda was glad to tell the kid how One Piece ends and that he was holding back his tears upon seeing the condition of Hinati Fujinami.
>   While Oda was fine with Hinati Fujinami learning about the One Piece ending, Oda requested to talk to the child alone so that details about the One Piece manga ending wouldn't be leaked while he jokingly pleaded to Hinati to not reveal it to the press.
>   JanNation AniManga noted that at the end of their talk, Hinati Fujinami was reportedly seen smiling but crying at the same time as he told the people that One Piece is "beautiful".

Comment: Again a well researched/written work of diligence!