# Where should I start watching in the Naruto series?

Tags: naruto

I'm not new to the Naruto franchise. I'm also up to date with what's currently going on (Madara vs Naruto & Sasuke). But I want to know the details of how everything happened. From which episode should I start watching? I want to at least start after the whole Pain storyline and around where the Fourth Ninja War starts. Anyone got an idea on where I should start?

Comment: First you should watch episode 42.  Then you should watch Episode 39, then episode 104, and then episode 96, followed by 11, 124, 138, and 8.  That should get you started

Comment: But for serious, Start with episode 1, or whichever episode is the newest one that you haven't seen.  Naruto isn't a very episodic show.  It doesn't really lend itself well to starting somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @SamIam is right, Naruto is not one of those shows where you can start in the middle and go on. I mean there might be a change where you can start in the middle, but they might mention something from the past. That might confuse you.

Comment: you should start from Pilot chapter  where Kyuubi is Naruto`s Dad . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the [Naruto arcs](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Arcs) wiki articles I found [Fourth shinobi world war: confrontation](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Shinobi_World_War:_Confrontation) to be the arc you are looking for.

As this is the point where the 4th ninja war starts.

> It spans through volumes 55 to 59, or more specifically, covers chapters 516 to 559 of the manga and episodes 261 to 270, and also picks from 272 to 289 of the Naruto: Shippūden anime and later picks up from episodes 296 to 310, and 312 to 321. The six episodes of the Power arc, along with two others, were shown in the interim. This arc is preceded by the Fourth Shinobi World War: Countdown and followed by the Fourth Shinobi World War: Climax.

So you can either start at chapter 516 or if you prefer the anime, start at episode 296 of Shippuuden to skip the pain arc, and jump straight into the war.

I would however advice you to just watch it all. If you do not wish to watch [17325 minutes of non-stop anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/10076/1458). You can also take a look at the [What can I skip](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/8788/1458) guide

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting at the beginning. If you try skipping around, you'll miss a lot of the key dynamics between the characters... even if there's a lot of filler, sometimes the filler episodes contain more backstory than you'd expect.