# Can I start watching Naruto Shippuden after Naruto Ep 135 and not miss anything? (Story wise)

Tags: naruto

I looked on the Naruto Filler list (http://www.animefillerlist.com/shows/naruto, this is the one I used for anyone asking) and it says that after episode 135 all the episodes just become filler. I was wondering to save myself a lot of time, could I just start watching Naruto Shippuden after ep 135

Comment: Yes you can watch Naruto Shippuden after ep 135 but some filler are good but in Shippuden there are no reference to the fillers

Comment: [Related/useful](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/8788/1458)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - yes. You can start watching Naruto Shippuden after watching episode 135 of Naruto without any harm to the overall Naruto storyline understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer for this is yes, you can just skip the whole filler arc, even without *watching ep220*, but it should be noted that those episodes **have manga materials** and connected to each other and to the end of 220 and to Shippudden:

Ep141, Ep142, Ep220

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. After Naruto episode 135 they are all fillers. However fillers are interesting to watch but Shippuden is better than the fillers. After episode 135 you can jump straight to Shippuden without missing any of the main storyline. Also, as  "Ch.Siva Ram Kishore" has added... There are zero references to the fillers from  Naruto in Naruto Shippuden.
Overall there are 220 episodes in Naruto and you only need to watch the first 135. The final 85 are all fillers and you can just Jump straight to Shippuden and save tons of time. SO YES.

(!! SKIP THE FILLERS AND GO STRAIGHT TO SHIPPUDEN !!)

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can but at first the first episode of shippuden was confusing but you still get the main story line but to get more detail and everything you should watch all of naruto then head to naruto shippuden but you can if you want just watch the first 135 episodes first or it will make absolutely no sense :p hope I helped you