# What season should I watch Naruto till, 5 or 9?

Tags: naruto

I just started watching *Naruto* on Netflix and it shows there are 9 seasons, but people say that there are only 5 though.

Should I only watch season 1-5 then go on to *Naruto Shippuden*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I start watching Naruto Shippuden after Naruto Ep 135 and not miss anything? (Story wise)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/48314/can-i-start-watching-naruto-shippuden-after-naruto-ep-135-and-not-miss-anything)

Answer (score 1):

**The confusion is possibly caused by non-standardized use of season numbering.**

The *Naruto* anime consists of 220 episodes.

In Japan, the anime is divided into [5 seasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto_episodes#Series_overview):

1. Season 1: 57 episodes
2. Season 2: 43 episodes
3. Season 3: 41 episodes
4. Season 4: 42 episodes
5. Season 5: 37 episodes

On the other hand, Netflix seems dividing each season into 26 episodes, resulting in a total of 9 seasons. This is the same as the series numbering used by UK's DVD Box, [Naruto Unleashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto_episodes#DVD).

So, all-in-all, both are possibly referring to the whole 220 episodes.

---

Though, perhaps coincidentally, Netflix's Season 5 ends on episode 130. As per [Can I start watching Naruto Shippuden after Naruto Ep 135 and not miss anything? (Story wise)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/48314/2516), almost all episodes after episode 135 are considered fillers, so it might be okay to skip Season 6-9 and continue to *Naruto Shippuden*.